# How to clean garbage fom begining of string stl string c++

Tags: c++, string, std, garbage

im reading simple string from file but when i see in the variable value i keep see garbage 
how can i clean it ?

```
string line;
ifstream fp_in;  // declarations of streams fp_in and fp_out
fp_in.open("test.txt",std::ios_base::in);    // open the streams
if(fp_in.is_open())
{
    while ( !fp_in.eof() )
        {       
        getline (fp_in,line,'\n');
...
...
```

but in the begging of "line" string i see :
ן»¿{"data":[{"id":"19513xxxx46141_326xxxx15447", ......
how can i get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8